# How to lower the bitrate of mp3 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mp3, audio-streaming

I made a Multipeer Audio Streaming app using the [Tony's tutorial](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity).
But I can only play .mp3 with 128kbps bit rate.
So I need to lower .mp3 with 192kbps or more bit rate to 128kbps.
I found a similar solution[[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693019/ios-lowering-bitrate-of-mpmediaitem-containing-an-ipod-music), but it's for encoding mp3 to video.

Please help me how to lower the bitrate.

Comment: see my edit, I have added bitrate key

Comment: There is an exception. I commented in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *assetOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:asset.tracks[0] outputSettings:nil];
```

You should provide `outputSettings:` on a server side (phone that streams audio)

So it should look like this.

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : @128000,
    AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatAppleIMA4),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @2,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey : @16,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey : @NO,
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : @NO
};
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *assetOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:asset.tracks[0] outputSettings:settings];
```

Comment: I don't use a streaming server. I use a iphone as a audio broadcaster and another iphone as audio listener. When I play the music .mp3 with 128kbps bit rate on broadcaster, I can play the music on listener. But more than 192kbps bit rate, there's no sound. So I need to lower bit rate to 128kbps.

Comment: There is an exception like this; 2014-09-26 16:31:18.039 MultipeerAudioStreamer[10376:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput initWithTrack:outputSettings:] AVAudioSettings dictionary must contain AVFormatIDKey'

Comment: I've updated post, you can use your specific format by changing kAudioFormatAppleIMA4

Comment: Same exception happened.

Comment: @Janos are you sure, you've copied the came code from updated answer?

Comment: Yes. Did you test it in Tony's tutorial mentioned before? Please help me with test.

Comment: can you send me your test project? i will take a look

Comment: Hi, l0gg3r. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes, but I can't run peer to test it correctly... i'll test it today evening, and will let you know about news

Comment: I solved it myself. Sorry, but it's not from your code.